# How jr instruction works in MIPS processor

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to understand with [MARS](https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/download.htm) and its MIPS X-Ray feature how `jr` instruction works, but I can't.

I know that `jr $ra` jumps to the direction recorded in `$ra`. This register is found during DECO phase, but after that (I guess during WB phase), it should be sent to PC register, but I can't see how.

[image: JR datapath in MARS application]

Can anyone explain to me how this instruction works during the 5-phases? Thanks!!

Comment: The upper right mux feeds back to PC, right?

Comment: I don't see a datapath that puts `$ra` into the `pc`.  There's no datapath directly from the registers, so the ALU out would be the next possibility but there's none there either.  Not too surprising though, these diagrams are simplifications.  I also don't see how `pc+4` is captured into `$ra` on `jal` — there needs to be a datapath from `pc+4` back to the `REGISTERS`.

Comment: Yes... I think it's a bit weird in this diagram. In the case of `jal`, I think it goes from ALU in the upper left side and links to the outline after _shift left 2_. Could be?

Comment: The block diagram provides the datapath for `jal`'s immediate to be combined with the `pc` and returned to the `pc` (but does not provide for not the capture of `pc+4` 
 into `$ra`).  The immediate in `jal`, comes from instruction memory directly upwards to a shift by 2, followed by joining (a dot) with `pc+4,` (which will pick up the upper 4 bits of the current `pc+4`, not shown), and return that combined value to the `pc`.